# After applying custom scrollbar to jqgrid,sorting is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have applied custome scrollbar to div "ui-jqgrid-bdiv",sorting is not working of jqgrid.Without custom scrollbar sorting is working fine.After applying custom scrollbar,after clicking on column it is giving blank grid.

CODE:-

```
 $(window).load(function(){
                $(".FilterContainer,.ui-jqgrid-bdiv").mCustomScrollbar({
                    scrollButtons:{enable:true},
                    theme:"light-thick"             
                });
});
     jQuery(gridOption).jqGrid({
    data: applyBestMachineData,
    datatype: "local",
    colNames:[displayName,'', 'kA$','%','kA$','%','kA$','%'],
    colModel:[    
        {name:'machineBestMachine',index:'machineBestMachine',width:350, sortable: false,classes: "machineBestMachinecol"},
        {name:'machineValue',index:'machineValue', width:60,sortable: false, classes: "machineValue"},
        {name:'applyBestMachineValue',index:'applyBestMachineValue', width:75,sortable: true, classes: "col2",sorttype:"text"},
        {name:'applyBestMachinePer',index:'applyBestMachinePer', width:75, align:"center", sortable: true,classes: "col1",sorttype:"text"},
        {name:'applyBestMachineOperation',index:'applyBestMachineOperation', width:65, align:"center",sortable: true, classes: "col2",sorttype:"text"},        
        {name:'applyBestMachineOperationPer',index:'applyBestMachineOperationPer', width:65,align:"right", sortable: false,classes: "col1"},        
        {name:'applyBothValue',applyBothValue:'applyBothValue', width:65,sortable: false, classes: "col2"},   
        {name:'applyBothPer',index:'applyBothPer', width:65,sortable: false, classes: "col1"}       
    ],
    rowNum:2000,
    rowTotal: 2000,         
    scroll:1,
    loadonce:true,
    mtype: "GET",
    rownumWidth: 40,
    gridview: true,
    autowidth: true,
    height:gridHeight,
    //sortable: false,          
    viewrecords: true, 
    onSelectRow: function(id) {     
        var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(id);       
        var machineBestMachineVar = rowData['machineBestMachine'];
        var machineBestMachineValue = machineBestMachineVar.split('<');     
        openEvaluationItemDetailPopUp(machineBestMachineValue[0]);
    },
    loadComplete: function() {
        //alert(this);

        $(gridOption+" tr:even").addClass('myAltRowClassEven');          
         $(gridOption+" tr:odd").addClass('myAltRowClassOdd');

            // $("#applyMachineGrid tr:even").addClass('myAltRowClassEven');             
            // $("#applyMachineGrid tr:odd").addClass('myAltRowClassOdd');

         }
});
```

Comment: You wrote that the problem exists only in case of applying "custom scrollbar" on the div "ui-jqgrid-bdiv", but **the code don't includes the applying**. You should provide the demo which can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added code of custom scrollbar.I have used jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js for custom scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer:-
  Just remove scroll=1 property